# Multiple google.maps.Marker displayed as one marker (overlay-ed positions)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm facing weird issue with google.maps.Markera's protyped object.

```
 ...
 function WMarker(config) {
   var cc = {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(...),
     map: map,
   };
   google.maps.Marker.call(this, cc);
 }
 WMarker.prototype = new google.maps.Marker();
 WMarker.constructor = WMarker;

 var m1 = new WMarker({...});
 var m2 = new WMarker({...});
 ...
```

will end with **ONLY ONE (latest) marker** displayed despite the positions are different.
Do you have any hints, where to look to fix this issue?

What I've checked:

- I'm able to create multiple pure google.maps.Marker(...)
- Put some delay between initializing WMarker
- When I call m2.setMap(null) I can see the the m1 marker.

Link to full example: http://pastebin.com/hSSCyRcP
   - if it runs with timeouts, it will remove only the first marker

Many Thanks,

Comment: I've tried to put two markers - EAST coast and WEST coast. The result is always the last one is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in all forums I found, that this was a bug.

From this link:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6447#c16

The solution to fix this issue is:
....

<s>WMarker.prototype = new google.maps.Marker();</s>

<s>WMarker.constructor = WMarker;</s>

```
function inherits(childCtor, parentCtor) { 
        / @constructor */ 
        function tempCtor() {}; 
        tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype; 
        childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype; 
        childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor(); 
        / @override */ 
        childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor; 
} 


inherits(WMarker, google.maps.Marker);
```